# Error message when trying to import installed python package

Tags: python, import, pip

I have python2.7 and python 2.6 installed in my VM and I pip install some libraries such as:

```
sudo pip install gsconfig
```

The installation is successful and I can see that the package is installed by:

```
pip list
```

My default system's python is 2.6. In the terminal I enter python and try to import the library as:

```
python
import gsconfig
```

And then I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named gsconfig
```

I also tried with python2.7 as:

```
python2.7
import gsconfig
```

I get the same error message. I can not understand why this is happening as I don't have with other packages this issue (e.g. simplejson).

Can it be that the location of the package is different? 
When I try this:

```
which gsconfig
```

I get:

```
/usr/bin/which: no gsconfig in (/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
```

**EDITED**
Also when I go to the site-packages folder of python2.7 I can see that the package is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the package name is not `gsconfig`, but is something else.

Looking at the [documentation](http://boundlessgeo.github.io/gsconfig/model.html), I think it's `geoserver`.